Inconsistent Web USB Communication on Windows Machines
I use the web USB for communication with the USB device having three sensors. It works fine on some of the Windows and all macOS machines. But in some Windows machines, it gets laggy and sometimes works fine on the same machine. I capture the data continuously. So what is the problem with this?
The code which I use is this:
const CMD1 = new Uint8Array([78, 84, 83, 83, 84, 65, 82, 84, 76, 238, 167, 78, 84, 69]);

const CMD2 = new Uint8Array([78, 84, 83, 83, 84, 65, 82, 84, 68, 40, 166, 78, 84, 69]);

var port = null;
port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
await port.open({
    baudRate: 115200
});
var selectedDevice = port.getInfo();
if (selectedDevice.usbProductId != 10 || selectedDevice.usbVendorId != 1240) {
const { writable, readable } = port;
writer = writable.getWriter();
reader = readable.getReader();
await writer.write(CMD1);
await writer.write(CMD2);
while (true) {
startLoopTimer();
const {
value,
done
} = await reader.read();
if (done) break;
console.log('Received data:', value);
}

My device details are shown in chrome://device-log:
Serial device added: path=COM5 instance id=USB\VID_04D8&PID_000A\5&2C179895&0&2 vid=04D8 p id=000A

USB device added: path=\?\usb#vid_04d8&pid_000a#5&2c179895&0&2#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed} vendor=1240 "Microchip Technology Inc.", product=10 "Simple CDC Device Demo", serial="", 

Serial device removed: path=COM5

USB device removed: path=\?\usb#vid_04d8&pid_000a#5&2c179895&0&2#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed} `quid`=3959900e-8309-4393-9be0-8c65dde53689

How can I make the communication smooth?
